# Cursor or rawquery crash,

Tags: java, android, sql

I'm newbie in android programming. I'm trying to create a database with
one table but it crashes:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "db";

    public static final String CREATE_ITEMS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE items ( _ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, code INTEGER," +     "item  TEXT,  description TEXT);";

    private static final String put = "insert into items (code,item,description) values (1,obj,obj info)";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(CREATE_ITEMS_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(put);

    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        android.util.Log.w("Constants", "Upgrading database, which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS constants");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

Cursor c;
DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);

c = db.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY code;", null);

if(c.moveToFirst()){
     String code= c.getString(1); 
     String item= c.getString(2);
     String info= c.getString(3);
}
```

As result I only get the first field right, the second is the field name and the third makes the program crash.

Comment: Share your logcat

Comment: `obj info` whats this?? you are using it as an variable, where as it doesn't have any value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here's a suggestion that should work out a little bit better for you. I've just now tested to see if it works and it executes without crashing and gives a little bit of output to verify the data.

I split it into two files, it's just personal flavour.

First, your DatabaseHelper class

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

/**
 * Created by shellstrom on 2017-05-29.
 */
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "db";
    public static final String CREATE_ITEMS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE items (_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, code INTEGER, item TEXT, description TEXT)";
    private static final String put = "INSERT INTO items (code,item,description) values ('','1', 'obj', 'obj info')";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_ITEMS_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(put);
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        android.util.Log.w("Constants", "Upgrading database, which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS items");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

then the MainActivity class I run the program from:

```
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Cursor c;
        DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        c = db.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY code", null);
        Log.d("TAG", "c count" +c.getCount());
        if(c.moveToFirst()){
            String code= c.getString(1);
            String item= c.getString(2);
            String info= c.getString(3);
            Log.d("TAG", "c1: " +code+ " c2: " +item+ " c3: " +info);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I haven't spent any time to fix other issues, such as making parameterised queries, error handling, etc. I just wanted to hand you at least something that compiles and runs based on your sample. If you have questions, please feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks. It strange although, if I just add some other field I got a "no such items table" error while compiling Select.

Comment: You may have to clean app data or uninstall the app before running again. The sqlite database may still exist when you run again and that means you will have to make sure it's deleted so that the CREATE_ITEMS_TABLE is executed again. I'll also recommend reading this http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html for much more in depth hands on sqlite use in Android.

Comment: I'm testing it on a physical device and I was unable to clear app data, so for now I just change the db name.

Comment: Ok, if you found any of the answers good enough so far, please mark one as accepted (by putting a green check mark on it) so that others who have the same problems can benefit as well.